# Devise don't want to return JSON after sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to configure my rails app to be able to do sign_in by JSON request (that part look to work), and after that I don't want to be redirected, I just want the sign_in return me a JSON with the user email and some other stuff.

Can someone tell me how to do that ?
I use the last version of rails with this gem [token authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) and devise.

For the moment I've created a custom session controller but I don't know what to put inside.
I'm new to rails so maybe it's easy but I can't find up to date answer to that.

Thank's

UPDATE : For information my main goal is to get back the auth token associated to the user after a sign_in success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override session create method of Devise::SessionsController

add a controller file in app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb and inherit Devise::SessionsController as below.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource) do |format|
      format.json {render :json => resource } # this code will get executed for json request
    end
  end

end
```

Add following in routes to consider the inherited User::SessionsController

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'users/sessions'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I do that, I always have a redirection, here my console log https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8998390 I just send a put request on /users/sign_in with the following data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8998402

Comment: "Processing by Api::SessionsController#create as */*", Try to initiate JSON request and it should get logged into the logfile as "Processing by Api::SessionsController#create as JSON". I had done the same thing long back, and fortunately I have to work again on the same thing by today. So, let me know if you will face any issue even after changing the request type to JSON.

Comment: I do my request with 
 curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in" -d'{ "user" : {"email" : "test@a.fr" , "password" : "12345678" } }' 
But still doesnt work, no way to get the Processing by "Api::SessionsController#create as */* as JSON" as you say.

Comment: Try this by adding .json to url -- curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json"; -d'{ "user" : {"email" : "test@a.fr" , "password" : "12345678" } }'

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the yield block to create additional code and return before hitting the redirect command

```
def create
  super do
    render json: { user: current_user, 
                   token: form_authenticity_token }.to_json and return
  end
end
```

`and return` will stop the controller from continuing on after the yield block.

`form_authenticity_token` - I've had to reset the csrf-token in header after sign-in.  This is one way to get the new csrf-token.